What are the filter size of these vintage lenses?
These lenses I have from the 1960s don't have a filter size marking; can someone find them out for me?

Minolta MC Rokkor-PF 1:1.4 58mm (5592305)
Minolta MC Tele Rokkor-QD 1:3.5 135mm (1531042)
Vivitar auto wide angle 1:2.5 28mm (22108979)


For Minolta lens the filter is 55mm
For Vivitar (with 22* as serial number and "AUTO WIDE-ANGLE" in the name) I found different information here. Some have 62mm, some 67mm.

Filter sizes are standardized, so you can measure the thread size of your lens with a ruler and figure that out.

One problem you can have is that some lenses used a 1mm thread instead of the usual .75mm one.
You can also get a set of step-up rings and check which ones fit your lenses. This will check diameter, thread pitch... and thread state because old lenses with worn out threads or no longer totally circular ones are not unheard of.

You do need to be pretty careful if you are going to take your own measurements though, and while I am all in favour of the metric system, it must be recognised that there are probably swathes of people who don't actually have metric measurements on the measuring devices they have to hand.

I used a metal ruler because it was more visible on the picture, but with a regular plastic office ruler risk is fairly minimal.  Can we assume that people who can reach PSE they can also use a calculator for the conversions?

I would not like to take measurements in 1/16ths of an inch on a plastic office ruler, trying to figure out if the distance from one inaccessible thread to the opposite inaccessible thread is, for example, 37mm or 39mm. And I see in the list you linked to, it also mentions 37.5mm! On top of that, I have a modern Sony lens sitting in front of me right now that takes 40.5mm filters... a measurement that is omitted from the list on Wikipedia.

Note, I'm not saying it's impossible to do it this way. My comment was just that it needs to be done with care and awareness.
